# How to use XMLEditor or an Editor plugin created in Eclipse RCP4

Tags: editor, eclipse-rcp, e4

I am newbie in Eclipse RCP so please help me this. Suppose I have a **SimpleTextEditor** extends **TextEditor** plugin created in Eclipse Kepler (4.x) with a **FileEditorInput** and **SimpleDocumentProvider**. How do I show this Editor and open a file in the editor in the Workbench or Part in application model.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Is this a pure 'e4' RCP application (using the application.e4xmi and no 3.x compatibility code)?

Comment: Yes, i want to make a pure e4 plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a pure e4 application you can not use the old Eclipse 3.x style editors. It is up to you to design how you want your part to work.

You can use the `org.eclipse.jface.text` `TextViewer` and similar but you can't use anything from `org.eclipse.ui.editors`

Edit:

You might want to look at [this work by Tom Schindl](http://wiki.eclipse.org/E4/UI/SimpleIDE) which includes a simple XML editor for e4 although it looks like it may be out of date. Source of this example XML editor can be found [here](https://eclipse.googlesource.com/e4/org.eclipse.e4.ui/+/integration/examples/org.eclipse.e4.demo.simpleide.editor.text/src/org/eclipse/e4/demo/simpleide/editor/text)

The Vogella [Migration Guide](http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4MigrationGuide/article.html) covers migration including the 3.x Bridge code which does allow you to use 3.x code in a e4 part.

Comment: Thanks greg. I will try with jface.text and TextViewer. In case using the 3.x compatible layer, do you have any suggestion or sample for that. My problem is showing the 3.x editor plugin in e4 Part.

Comment: @user3090010 added link to migration guide which covers this

Comment: Thank @greg, I will update back when resolve this issue